# Prove that the mapping is order preserving

Tags: order-theory

$ P=Q=\{ \mathcal{P}(S); \subseteq \} $ and $\phi$ from $P \rightarrow Q$ is defined by
$\\  \phi (U)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\{1\} & \text{if} \; 1 \in U \\
\{2\} & \text{if} \; 2\in U, \; 1 \notin U\\
\emptyset & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array} \right. $

Comment: For the images of $\phi$, do you mean $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$ and $\emptyset$?

Comment: @Darsen hey yes, I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not order preserving, since $\{2\}\subseteq\{1,2\}$, but $\phi(\{2\})=\{2\}\nsubseteq\{1\}=\phi(\{1,2\}).$

Comment: If $\phi$ were order preserving then whenever $U\subseteq V$ we should have $\phi(U)\subseteq \phi(V)$. In this example we are considering $U=\{2\}$ and $V=\{1,2\}$, which satisfy $U\subseteq V$, but we don't have however $\phi(U)\subseteq \phi(V)$.

Comment: What do we do if $ P= \{ \mathcal{P}(S); \subseteq \} ; Q=2$ and $\phi$ from $P \rightarrow Q$ is defined by
 $\\  \phi (U)=  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & x \in U\\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array} \right. $

Comment: Do we assume an arbitrary $U,V \subseteq P$ and $U \subseteq V$ and solve?

Comment: no I am writing 2 only not $ \{2\}$

Comment: If $Q=\{\{2\}\}$ then it doesn't make sense to say $\phi: P\to Q$ can give the images $\{1\}$ or $\{0\}$, since the only element in $Q$ is $\{2\}$

Comment: Here Q is one fold product of 2